# how to show the following is euclidean domain...??

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following is Euclidean domain??

1.$Z_{2}[i][x]$

2.$Z_{3}[i][x]$

3.$Z_{5}[i][x]$

4.$Z_{15}[i][x]$

And how to we prove this??

I know the 2 properties of Euclidean domain..except that how we show this?

Comment: $Z_{15}[i][x]$ is not even a domain.

Comment: Anyway, what is the *two properties of Euclid domain* you know? Stating them makes easy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. The ring $\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$ is not a domain, since $(1 + i)^2 = 0$.
2. First see that we have the following ring isomorphism: $\mathbb{Z}_3[i] \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3 [y] }{(y^2 + 1)}$ and the polynomial $y^2 + 1$ is irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[y]$ (why?). Thus $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}_3[i][x]$ is an Euclidean Domain.
3. The ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[i]$ is not a domain, since $(1 + 2i)(1 - 2i) = 0$.
4. The ring $\mathbb{Z}_{15}[i]$ is not a domain, since $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is not a domain. (this fact is already pointed out by tetori).